# Запуск Entity Framework в контейнере Docker

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, docker, entity-framework

Есть веб-приложение на ASP .NET 7, в котором установлена зависимость Entity Framework (файл `WebApplication.csproj`):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.10">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Приложение запускается в контейнере Docker (содержимое файла `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build



# Добавляем Entity Framework CLI в образ
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.10
ENV PATH "$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"



FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Окончательный образ для запуска приложения
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

Как видно в файле, мы при сборке образа устанавливаем команду `dotnet-ef`. Далее с помощью `docker compose up` запускаем наши контейнеры.

Проблема в том, что если зайти в контейнер (`docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`) и попробовать выполнить команду `dotnet ef` (или любую другую), то получаю ошибку:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'dotnet-ef' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Пробовал в `Dockerfile` добавить строки:

```
# Установка .NET SDK для Entity Framework
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https && \
    apt install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

Но получаю сообщение о том, что `dotnet-sdk-7.0` в репозитории не найден:

```
...
5.703 Reading package lists...
6.579 Building dependency tree...
6.766 Reading state information...
6.927 E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-6.0
6.927 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-7.0'
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt update &&     apt install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https &&     apt install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Та же самая проблема, если пробую установить .NET SDK не версии 7.0, а 6.0. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть рабочие конфигурации, как использовать Entity Framework в контейнере Docker? Потому что я не знаю, в правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь, в чём моя ошибка и где что нужно исправить. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: а зачем вам еф в контейнере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы ставите `dotnet-ef` в другом Stage. В вашем `Dockerfile` используется [Multi-Stage Build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/), который позволяет собрать приложение "из нескольких этапов":

- используем SDK образ (sdk:7.0)
- он позволяет сделать build и publish
- потом берем Runtime образ (aspnet:7.0)
- и копируем готовое приложение в этот образ
- из этого финального образа приложение и запускается

Это нужно чтобы создать минимальный образ и без лишних зависимостей, т.к. для выполнения приложения не нужен полный SDK образ. Подробно как это работает и как пользоваться описано в офф. документации докера.

В вашем случае `dotnet-ef` устанавливается в SDK образе и не копируется в итоговый образ. Поэтому он и не доступен, а команда `dotnet tool ...` в runtime образах не работает.

Решить это можно:

- отказавшись от multi-stage build и просто использовать один SDK образ всегда, но multi-stage build считается "best practice" при создании настоящих продакшн образов
- или оставить как есть, но дополнительно копировать `dotnet-ef` из SDK образа в финальный образ (из папки `/root/.dotnet/tools/`), подробно это описано тут: https://andrewlock.net/running-net-core-global-tools-in-non-sdk-docker-images/
- или не использовать `dotnet-ef` внутри контейнера вообще, а накатывать миграции, например, с хоста